# Migrate J2EE Application over Pivotal Cloud Fountry 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ejb, cloud-foundry

I have quite big J2ee Web App right now running on IBM WAS 8 that should be moved over PCF 2.0 environment. The web application leverage on EJB 3 services.

Are there any alternative to convert EJB service to Spring Boot services during migration? I'd like to avoid dockers if possibile.

many thanks

Comment: Can you describe more about what you want to do?  Spring Boot is aimed at a partial JEE environment (i.e. no EJB's) and "converting" is rather open ended.

Comment: Sure. I have 2 EAR files. one containing the war (JSF 2, Spring, ...), a second one containing the services (EJB 3, Spring, hibernate). I'd like to keep the application as much as possibile as right now and preventing to disassemble it to became cloud-native. What I am looking for is some ideas/cases to start digging in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Any application that you upload in to your space in PCF can support microservices Architecture pattern.

- Upload your J2EE APP
- Convert all your EJB Related services in to a Spring Boot App and upload those Apps in to same space

  - Ensure those Spring Boot Apps exposes HTTP REST Endpoints
- Access the REST Endpoints from your J2EE App.

It's pretty simple !!